# Lucene to bring cheeseburger when searching for burger

Tags: lucene

I would like that if a lucene document contains the word **cheeseburger** and a user searches for **burger** for this documents to come up. I see that I will probably need a custom analyzer to break this compound word into **cheese** and **burger**. However, breaking words may also bring irrelevant results.

Ex: if when indexing production we index **product** and **ion** as well, then when the user searches for **ion** documents containing **production** will come out, which is not relevant.

So a simple word breaker won't cut it. I need a way of knowing that **cheeseburger** is associated to **burger** and **cheese**, but that **production** is not associated to **ion**.

Is there a more intelligent process to achieve this?

Does this has a name just like stemming is to reduce words to their root form?

Comment: +1 because I am eating a cheeseburger at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how accurate you want your synonymy to be, you might need to look into approaches such as [Latent Semantic Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_indexing) (LSA) and its variants such as LDA etc. A simpler approach would be to use an Ontology such as [Wordnet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) to augment your searches. A wordnet Lucene index is available. However if your scenario includes domain-specific vocab then you might need to generate a "mapping" Ontology.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [DictionaryCompoundWordTokenFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/compound/DictionaryCompoundWordTokenFilter.html) which uses a brute-force algorithm to split compound nouns based on a dictionary.

Comment: Wouldn't this break "production" into "product" and "ion"? I want to avoid breaking words to irrelevant simpler words.

Comment: It depends on what there is in your dictionary. If production is in your dictionary and that the filter is configured to prefer longest matches (see constructor), the word won't be splitted.

Comment: To be more precise, if you dictionary contains exactly "product", "ion", "production", "cheese" and "burger" then it will behave as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

in most cases you can simply use wildcard queries with a leading wildcard *burger. You only have to enable the support for leading wildcards on your query parser:

```
parser = new QueryParser(LuceneVersion.getVersion(), searchedAttributes, analyzer);
parser.setAllowLeadingWildcard(true);
```

Take care: 
Leading wildcards might slow your search down.

If you need a more specific solution I would suggest to go with stemming. If really a matter of finding the right analyzer.
There are stemming implementations for several languages e.g. the SnowballAnalyzer (http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/snowball/SnowballAnalyzer.html).

Best regards,

Chris

Comment: thanks. But I want to avoid the wildcard solution since as you said is slow. I tried the stemming analyzer but it does not work; for this specific example it reduces the word to "cheeseburg" so when a user searches for "burger" it is reduced to "burg" and it is still not able to find it.

Comment: Another solution would be to copy your content to a seperate field and run an N-Gram analyzer for that field. It will split up your words into several pieces. It might split them up to much tough... or as you said it probably will split up words that you don't like to be split. You just have to try that out...

Answer (score 0):

Getting associations by looking at the word is not going to scale to other words. For example, you cannot know "whopper" is associated with burger and "big-mac" is associated with cheese just by looking at the words. To make the search aware of the associations, you probably need a database of associations like "A is a B" or "A contains B". (As Mikos has mentioned, I think WordNet provides such a database.) Then, when you see B in a query, you translate the query so that it also searches for A.

Answer (score 0):

I think the underlying question is -- how big is the collection you are indexing? If you are indexing some collection where all of the synonyms and related words are already known, then the index can just include the synonyms and related words directly, like 'cheeseburger' including the related words 'cheese' and 'burger'. (An approach successfully used in the LOINC standard medical terms Lucene index.)

If you are trying to solve the general problem for a whole human language (English, Chinese, etc.) then you have to move to some kind of semantic analysis as mentioned above.

It might be useful to talk with the subject matter experts of the area you are indexing to see how they search for terms -- what synonyms/related words do they use, do they have defined lists of synonyms/related words, do they need/use stemming, etc. This should give you some idea as to which approach (direct synonym/related-word inclusion or semantic analysis) you need to pursue.